# AngularJS refreshing page intermittently throws an uncaught object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a routes file that is loading a controller and partial html when it hits the index. I am using the http-server with default configuration that comes with the angular-seed project. So I am starting the server using npm start.

The problem is that the first time I hit the page right after I start the server, the page seems to be loading fine. But if I sit there and refresh the page a bunch, I start to get an uncaught object error that looks like this,

```
Uncaught object angular.js:78
    (anonymous function) angular.js:78
    (anonymous function) angular.js:3948
    forEach angular.js:320
    loadModules angular.js:3909
    createInjector angular.js:3849
    doBootstrap angular.js:1510
    bootstrap angular.js:1525
    (anonymous function) app.js:12
    n.Callbacks.j jquery.js:3073
    n.Callbacks.k.fireWith jquery.js:3185
    n.extend.ready jquery.js:3391
    I jquery.js:3407
```

app.js

```
"use strict";

define("app", ["angular", "routes", "angular-resource", "angular-route", "jQuery"], function (angular) {
    var app = angular.module("app", [
        "ngResource", 
        "ngRoute", 
        "app.customerApp"
    ]);

    angular.element().ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
    });

    return app;
});
```

routes.js

```
"use strict";

require(["app", "components/app/app-ctrl", "components/customer/customer-ctrl"], function(app) {
    return app.config(["$routeProvider", "$resourceProvider", 
    function ($routeProvider, $resourceProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            controller: "CustomerCtlr", 
            templateUrl: "/app/partials/customer.html"
        }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);
});
```

customer-ctrl.js

```
'use strict';

define("customerApp", ["angular", "angular-resource"], function(angular) {
    var customerApp = angular.module('app.customerApp', ["ngResource"]);
    return customerApp;
});

require(["customerApp"], function(customerApp) {
    customerApp.controller("CustomerCtlr", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

    }]);
});
```

I have found out by putting in console.logs in the app.js, routes.js, and the controller that they are loading in different orders every time. Why is this happening? RequireJS is supposed to be preventing that.

Comment: What is in app.js:12 ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem I was trying to avoid pasting my entire application, but I updated it for you and put in the relevant things. I believe its the controller causing a problem, though it looks right to me, and was working before, and still works sometimes.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using ? Is it minified ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem Yes its minified and its version 1.3.0-build.2801+sha.ff791c9. I got it with bower.

Comment: 1. It is a good idea to end minified filenames with `.min.&lt;ext&gt;`. 2. Don't use minified code when debugging.

Comment: It is ended with .min.js. I am using RequireJS hence no extensions on these things because I have paths to them in a config file.

Comment: @ExpertSystem That was the problem man. The min version was causing an error for some reason. Switching the the full file fixed it. Weird, maybe you could tell me why?

Comment: @ExpertSystem I take that back. Its working almost all the time now. Still breaks after a ton of refreshes for some reason. If you put your answer up i will give you credit for it.

Comment: Ehm...what answer ? I did not (by any means) imply that using unminified versions solves any problem (nor should it be used in production environments). What I meant is that when using unminified code (for **debugging** purposes only), the stack traces of error you get make more sense and give more information.

Comment: It sounds like a nasty timng-bug. Could you post the stack trace you get with the unminified code ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem Yeah I think it is a timing but. Ill post it. One second. It is still happening sometimes.

Comment: @ExpertSystem Whats the best way to get the stack trace in chrome?

Comment: It's the error that you posted above (I assume you copied it from the DevTools console). Just copy the error that happens with the unminified version (so we might gain more insight on what/where is wrong).

Comment: @ExpertSystem Okay I put the newest stack trace up. I just overwrote the old one.

Comment: @ExpertSystem I think I see the problem. The routes file depends on the app being loaded, but the controllers only depend on the app being loaded, though they also need to wait for routes to be loaded. Though I am not very good with requirejs so I am not sure how to change it yet.

Comment: @ExpertSystem So essentially, I need to define the routes module, and have the controllers require it. But the routes module also has to ensure it is requiring app module still...

Comment: I am not a fan of RequireJS, so I can't help you much...